# Google Apps Script spreadsheet triggers expiring

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I have a shared google spreadsheet with rows representing accounts and the state of those accounts. 
Accounts can go from being outlined, to signed, to ordered.

I want it so that when an account is Edited from Outlined -> to Signed, I send an email to the person responsible for the "Ordering" portion.

Because I can't send emails inside the `onEdit(e)` trigger, I have made a custom function, customOnEdit which will listen to the same events and send the email. This works fine.

```
function customOnEdit(e) {
    process(e);
}
```

What happens next will shock you:

*The trigger will simply stop working*

The trigger will go from being regular black, to being greyed out. Any edits will not send any emails:
[Trigger greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPsX7.png)

It can be weeks later. It can be just the next day. But because of this I have to check it daily and reset it otherwise things will stop flowing.

How can I deal with this issue?